# Using 2 tables for JOIN condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I select 2 tables for JOIN conditions,

I'm try to query special prices for all customers(need for export) and there are 3 types of product discounts per customer stored in 3 tables,

What I'm trying to get is (price is sample pricing):

```
type | sku | Unit_Price | customer_group
---------------------------
item | DS875 | 50         | COMPANY X
item | DS875 | 25       |   COMPANY Y
item | DS875 | 30       |   COMPANY Z
item | DS544 | 50         | COMPANY X
item | DS544 | 25       |   COMPANY Y
item | DS544 | 30       |   COMPANY Z
item | DS855 | 50         | COMPANY X
item | DS855 | 25       |   COMPANY Y
item | DS855 | 30       |   COMPANY Z
```

Here is my query

```
SELECT 'item' AS type, p.PRODUCT_SKU AS sku, 
    CASE 
        WHEN pp.PRICE IS NULL AND pp.PRICE > 0 
        THEN
            pp.PRICE
        WHEN cp.Price IS NOT NULL AND cp.Price > 0 
        THEN
            cp.Price
        WHEN c.MarkupDiscount <> 0 
        THEN
                p.PRODUCT_PRICE -
                (p.PRODUCT_PRICE / 100 * c.MarkupDiscount)

    END AS Unit_Price,
    c.COMPANY_NAME AS customer_group
FROM
T002_PRODUCTS p
LEFT JOIN CUSTOMERS c ON c.VISIBLE = 1 AND c.ACTIVE = 1
RIGHT JOIN PROMOTION_PRICES pp ON 
                           (c.CUSTOMER_ID = pp.CUSTOMER_ID AND 
                            p.PRODUCT_ID = pp.PRODUCT_ID) AND 
                            pp.ACTIVE = 1 AND pp.DATE_FROM <= GETDATE() AND 
                            pp.DATE_TO >= GETDATE()
RIGHT JOIN AFC cp ON (c.CUSTOMER_ID = cp.HH AND 
                      cp.VC = p.PRODUCT_ID) AND cp.SA = 1
```

Can't figure out how to get this right :)

SAMPLE DATA

PRODUCTS

```
PRODUCT_ID|PRODUCT_SKU|PRODUCT_PRICE
____________________________________
8         | DS544     | 3.99
9         | DS855     | 5
10        | DS875     | 7
```

CUSTOMERS

```
CUSTOMER_ID | COMPANY_NAME | MarkupDiscount | VISIBLE | ACTIVE
______________________________________________________
78         | COMPANY X  |  15          |  1     | 1
79         | COMPANY Y  |  0           |  1     | 1
80         | COMPANY Z  |  0           |  1     | 1
```

PROMOTION_PRICES

```
CUSTOMER_ID | PRODUCT_ID | DATE_FROM   | DATE_TO    | ACTIVE | PRICE
____________________________________________________________
78          |  8         | '2018-01-01'|'2019-01-01'| 1      | 50
```

AFC

```
HH | VC | SA | Price
_____________________
80 |  8 |  1 | 50
```

Comment: You are not joining anything for customers table

Comment: @Monty, can you please provide sample data and your expected output in table format - that will be helpful for getting your desired answer

Comment: @AjanBalakumaran I'm using customer table for `customer_group` results and all JOINs use it as condition

Comment: @MONTY "FROM
T002_PRODUCTS p LEFT JOIN CUSTOMERS c ON c.VISIBLE = 1 AND c.ACTIVE = 1" in this part of your code you are not joining anything from product table to customer table

Comment: @AjanBalakumaran This is where I need help, as I'm using it on JOINs how should I select it?

Comment: RIGHT JOIN... Most people find LEFT JOIN tricky enough to get... It's much easier to understand `main table left join optional data` instead of `optional data right join main table`.

Answer (score 0):

This is untested:

```
SELECT
    'item'         AS type
  , p.PRODUCT_SKU  AS sku
  , CASE
        WHEN pp.PRICE IS NULL AND
            pp.PRICE > 0 THEN pp.PRICE
        WHEN cp.Price IS NOT NULL AND
            cp.Price > 0 THEN cp.Price
        WHEN c.MarkupDiscount <> 0 THEN p.PRODUCT_PRICE -
            (p.PRODUCT_PRICE / 100 * c.MarkupDiscount)
    END            AS Unit_Price
  , c.COMPANY_NAME AS customer_group
FROM AFC cp
INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS c
    ON cp.HH = c.CUSTOMER_ID AND c.VISIBLE = 1 AND c.ACTIVE = 1
INNER JOIN T002_PRODUCTS p
    ON cp.VC = p.PRODUCT_ID
INNER JOIN PROMOTION_PRICES pp
    ON c.CUSTOMER_ID = pp.CUSTOMER_ID
    AND p.PRODUCT_ID = pp.PRODUCT_ID
    AND GETDATE() BETWEEN pp.DATE_FROM AND pp.DATE_TO
WHERE cp.SA = 1
```

Choosing the "from table" is IMHO critical to making queries easy to follow. Here the only table that has both client and product is AFC, and because we need both to make this work, start with that. From then on the relationships appear to be clear.

**tip:** *many seasoned SQL users never use "right join", this isn't because it is bad or incorrect, it is purely because you can always alter the sequence of tables to avoid this join type. Then the "flow" of joins is easier to follow in a "top to bottom" fashion. Once right joins are introduced you need to think in the opposite direction and this can get quite confusing. So, once you see yourself using right joins, pause and re-consider what table you really want to start with.*

*nb: not everyone will agree with this tip, but many more will.*